# How to pass ngModel value to component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, paypal, angular6

I'am working on Angular 6 E-Commerce project and integrating PayPal payment to it. I've added the paypal button in html where I'am getting amount in [(ngModel)], but, I've to pass it in component file so that it can be read in paypal config. Any better or alternative solution is highly praised

Following are the files:

1. shopping-cart-summary.html

```
<div *ngIf="cart$ | async as cart">
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="cart.totalPrice">
  <div id="paypal-checkout-btn"></div> 
</div>
```

2. shopping-cart-summary.ts

```
totalPrice: number;

public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  const elementExists: boolean = !!document.getElementById('paypal-checkout-btn');
  if(elementExists && !this.addScript) {
    this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
      paypal.Button.render({
        client: {
            sandbox: 'My sandbox API',
        },
        payment: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                  transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total:    this.totalPrice,
                            currency: 'USD'
                        },
                        payee:{email:'My Email ID'},
                    }
                ]
                }
            });
        },
        commit: true,
        locale: 'en_US',
        style: {
            size:   'medium', // tiny, small, medium
            color:  'blue', // orange, blue, silver
            shape:  'pill'    // pill, rect
        },
        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' or 'production'
        onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.payment.execute().then((payment) => {
                console.log('payment 1 completed!');
            });
        },
        onCancel: (data) => {
            console.log('payment 1 was cancelled!');
        }
    }, '#paypal-checkout-btn');
      this.paypalLoad = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Here I'am getting value in [(ngModel)] as $182 which I want to pass it in component file, so how to do it? Any suggestions??

Here is the screenshot of the total price of products
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to pass it in component file"?

Comment: I mean how to pass cart.totalprice of ngModel in component file which I'am getting as  $182

Comment: You would need to subscribe to `cart$` to get the value of totalPrice, unless you pipe the value of `cart$` into `this.addPaypalScript()`.

Comment: subscribe method is not available in cart$. when I do console.log(this.cart$) I get : Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `cart$` is an observable, you will either need to subscribe to it to get the value or use it in a pipeable operator.

Try this:

```
cart$: Observable<any>;
totalPrice: number;

public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    const elementExists: boolean = !!document.getElementById('paypal-checkout-btn');

    cart$.subscribe((cart: any) => {
        this.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;
    })

  if(elementExists && !this.addScript && this.totalPrice) {
    this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
        paypal.Button.render({
            client: {
                sandbox: 'My sandbox API',
            },
            payment: (data, actions) => {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: {
                                    total: this.totalPrice,
                                    currency: 'USD'
                                },
                                payee: { email: 'My Email ID' },
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            commit: true,
            locale: 'en_US',
            style: {
                size: 'medium', // tiny, small, medium
                color: 'blue', // orange, blue, silver
                shape: 'pill'    // pill, rect
            },
            env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' or 'production'
            onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
                return actions.payment.execute().then((payment) => {
                    console.log('payment 1 completed!');
                });
            },
            onCancel: (data) => {
                console.log('payment 1 was cancelled!');
            }
        }, '#paypal-checkout-btn');
        this.paypalLoad = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot dude... Finally got the value and you saved my day.....

Comment: Thanks man Finally I have completed the project, was stuck for 5 days and today got a huge relief. Well, one last thing, my project is working perfectly fine, but, only one minor error as:  'Uncaught Error: PayPal Checkout Integration Script with same version (4.0.268) already loaded on page'. It doesn't hamper my project flow, but, still the error

Comment: I'd need to see more code to understand the error, which shouldn't affect you anyway. Sounds like you're referencing the paypal script multiple times somewhere/somehow.

Comment: Ok thanks again... I will go through it again... try to solve it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of totalPrice: number; in your component.ts use cert = {"totalPrice": 0};
Else use totalPrice in your component.html instead of cert.totalPrice.

Comment: It isn't possible to pass the value of ngModel in component file?

Comment: What do you mean by component file.

Comment: component file that is in component.ts... Getting value from ngModel and passing it in totalPrice defined in component.ts

Comment: In order to make two way binding effective, the object should be there in ts and html file together. I could not see that in your code. Mkae it as simple as possible. Add a variable on ts and use it in html. You will achieve what you want.